# Conectar a través de Google Apps Script a una base de datos MS Access

Tags: javascript, ms-access, google-apps-script

Necesito rescatar periódicamente, por lo menos una vez al día, a una base de datos hecha en MS Access, que esta alojada en un servidor de red local.

La idea principal es poder copiar los datos de esta base de datos y volcarlos sobre un sheet de google, para poder compartir con el resto usuarios del sheet los datos que se van modificando cada día de la base de datos de MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script no puede acceder a servidores de red local.

Podrías

1. alojar la base de datos de MS Access en alguna nube que soporte JDBC y luego seguir las indicaciones de https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc
2. usar la API de Google Apps Script o mejor aún directamente la API de Google Sheets para que desde Access hagas la publicación a la hoja de cálculo de Google
3. volcar los datos a un un archivo y usar Google Drive Backup and Sync o Google Drive Filestream para subirlo a Google Drive y luego usar Google Apps Script para leer el archivo.
4. ..

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.
El punto 1, no lo veo factible de poder hacer en mi empresa El punto 2 no lo acabo de entender del todo, desde access hacer el volcado a google sheet? Eso se tendría que hacer desde access, no? El punto 3 es el que voy a probar, no había caído en algo así, y lo resultón que puede ser.
Lo que me faltaría es conseguir que el access me haga el volcado diario.

Comment: @asantro Si te animas a intentar el punto 2 y tienes alguna duda, no dejes de publicar una pregunta al respecto. Buena suerte con el punto 3, te agradeceré me compartas cómo te fue.